# Queueing Theory: How to estimate steady-state queue length for single queue, N servers?

Tags: poisson-distribution, networks, simulation, queueing

I have a real-life situation that can be solved using Queueing Theory.
This should be easy for someone in the field.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Scenario:**
There is a single Queue and **N** Servers.
When a server becomes free, the Task at the front of the queue gets serviced.
The mean service time is **T** seconds.
The mean inter-Task arrival time is **K** * **T** (where **K** > 1)
(assume Poisson or Gaussian distributions, whichever is easier to analyze.)

**Question:**
At steady state, what is the length of the queue?  (in terms of **N**, **K**).

**Related Question:**
What is the expected delay for a Task to be completed?

Here is the real-life situation I am trying to model:
I have an Apache web server with 25 worker processes.
At steady-state there are 125 requests in the queue.
I want to have a theoretical basis to help me optimize resources
and understand quantitatively how adding more worker processes
affects the queue length and delay.

I know the single queue, single server, Poisson distribution is well analyzed.
I don't know the more general solution for **N** servers.

thanks in advance,
-- David Jones
dxjones@gmail.com

Comment: Quick look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_model says that the case N servers one queue is also well analyzed.

Comment: It would help to know the distribution of service times. Is it constant (m/d/n), exponential (m/m/n) or some other distribution (m/g/n).